# Combinatorial identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, generating-functions, young-tableaux

Let $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ be n positive consecutive integers. So I want to know if there exists a close combinatorial form for the coefficient of $x^k$ in 
$$(x+a_1)(x+a_2)\ldots (x+a_n)    .$$
In particular is there something nice for $a_1=1,\ldots,a_n=n$?

Comment: Lookup [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas) and the [rising factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RisingFactorial.html).

Comment: For the particular case see [Stirling Numbers of the First Kind](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). Although for that $a_1=0,a_2=1,\ldots ,a_n=n-1$.